# Blowfish Encrypt and Decrypt char buffers

Tags: c, linux, encryption, openssl

i'm try to get a bowfish function working for simple char buffers. The program fails when I try to decrypt an encrypted buffer and fails on the EVP_CipherFinal_ex() call.

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <openssl/evp.h> 
#include <openssl/buffer.h> 
#include <openssl/blowfish.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int do_crypt(unsigned char *inbuf, int inlen, unsigned char *outbuf, int *outlen, int do_encrypt) { 
     outbuf=(unsigned char*) malloc(inlen+EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH); 
     int tmplen=0; 
     unsigned char key[] = "0123456789"; 
     unsigned char iv[] = "12345678"; 

     EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx; 
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx); 
     EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL, do_encrypt); 
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(&ctx, 10); 
     EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, do_encrypt); 

     if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, outlen, inbuf, inlen)) { 
         /* Error */ 
         printf("* update failed *\n"); 
         EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx); 
         return 0; 
     } 

     int db=*outlen; 

     if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf+db, &tmplen)) { 
         /* Error */ 
          ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); 
         printf("* finalise failed *\n"); 
         EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx); 
         return 0; 
     } 


     (*outlen)=db+tmplen; 

     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx); 

     return 1; 
} 
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
     char *plain="ENCRYPT DECRYPT this string"; 
     int plain_len=strlen(plain); 
     unsigned char *cipher; 
     int cipher_len; 

     printf("***** ENCRYPT *****\n"); 
     if (!do_crypt((unsigned char*) plain, strlen(plain), cipher, &cipher_len, 1)) { 
         printf("failed to encrypt\n"); 
         return 1; 
     } 

     char *decrypt; 
     int decrypt_len; 
     printf("***** DECRYPT *****\n"); 
     if(!do_crypt(  cipher ,cipher_len , decrypt, &decrypt_len, 0)) { 
         printf("failed to decrypt\n"); 
         return 1; 
     }
 printf("decrypt=\"%s\"\n",decrypt); 
 printf("decrypt_len=%d\n",decrypt_len); 
     return 0; 
}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And *how* do it fail? What errors do you get? What is the expected output of your program, and what is the actual output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Segmentation fault '140536099350160:error:06065064:lib(6):func(101):reason(100):evp_enc.c:539:'

Comment: There's also an example of how to use the `EVP_*` interfaces for encryption and decryption on the OpenSSL wiki. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Comment: If anyone is interested i found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727646/what-is-the-length-parameter-of-aes-evp-decrypt)!

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* problems: The first is that [you should not cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). This is the most likely reason `EVP_CipherUpdate` crashes.

The second error is that arguments in C are passed *by value*, meaning they are copied and the functions only have copies of the arguments passed by the caller. This means that in the `do_crypt` function when you assign to the argument `output` you are only assigning to the local copy inside the function, the variable `cipher` in the `main` function will not be changed.

The last problem can be solved by imitating *pass by reference* by passing a pointer to the pointer, and use the address-of operator `&` and the dereference `*` operator:

```
/*                                     Note extra indirection */
/*                                                          | */
/*                                                          v */
int do_crypt(unsigned char *inbuf, int inlen, unsigned char **outbuf, int *outlen, int do_encrypt) {
    ...
    *output = malloc(...);
    ...
    if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, *outbuf, outlen, inbuf, inlen)) { ... }
    ...
 }
```

You then call it like

```
do_crypt((unsigned char*) plain, strlen(plain), &cipher, &cipher_len, 1)
```

Comment: the problem is when i try to decrypt the  the char buffers and i try what you suggested however did not work and rise so many errors.

Comment: @FlanAlflani Try fixing those errors (and possible warnings). If you don't know how to fix all errors, post a new question with the modified code and include the complete the complete and unedited error and warning logs. Also remember that in the function you have to think about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) when adding the dereference oprator. For example you have e.g. `outbuf+db` in your original code, which you should change to `(*output)+db`.

Comment: @FlanAlflani But I really fail to see where you could get errors. The only thing I see is a warning from the `malloc` call if you don't follow the link in my answer and read about why you should not cast `malloc` and how to fix those warnings.